# Aspettare (da) + time period

Tags: difference, prepositions

What is the difference between the following sentences?

- ho aspettato tre anni
- ho aspettato da tre anni

I thought that the latter was the correct one, but I have read the former today.

Comment: "Ti aspetto da tre ore" means that you began to wait someone three hours ago and you are still waiting for him/her. "Ti aspetto tre ore" means that you will wait someone for three hours and then you will stop waiting for him/her.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you intend to say?

a) “Ho aspettato tre anni” means that, sometime in the far or immediate past, I experienced a wait that lasted 3 years. For instance, *Dopo le superiori ho aspettato tre anni e poi mi sono iscritto all'università*.

b) “Aspetto da tre anni” means that I am presently waiting and have been doing so starting 3 years ago. More colloquially, and expressing some impatience, “Sono tre anni che aspetto”.

c) “Aspetto tre anni” (or “per tre anni”) means that I am waiting now, or about to start, and intend to do so for 3 years. For instance, *Aspetto tre anni e, se non trovo un lavoro, vado in Inghilterra*.

d) “Ho aspettato da tre anni” sounds unusual. If you mean the meaning b), but in the past, you'd probably use the imperfect tense; say, *Aspettavo da tre anni quando finalmente è arrivato il principe azzurro*.

Comment: The second sentence was in the present tense. Sorry for the confusion.